# How to link Title in object model

Tags: client-object-model, hyperlink

I am displaying all blog posts Titles on post page. But I want to link those post so that user should click on that.

Below is my code.

```
<label id="labelHTML"></label><script type="text/javascript">

var listoperation =null;
var clientContext = null;
var web = null;
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Initialize, "sp.js");
function Initialize()
{
clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
web = clientContext.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Posts");

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
var q = '<View><RowLimit>5</RowLimit></View>';
camlQuery.set_viewXml(q);
this.listItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
//var listId = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId;
//var itemId = parseInt(GetUrlKeyValue('ID'));


clientContext.load(listItems, 'Include(DisplayName,Id,testchoice)');
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onListItemsLoadSuccess), 
Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
function onListItemsLoadSuccess(sender, args) {

$('#labelHTML').html('');
    var listEnumerator = this.listItems.getEnumerator();
    //iterate though all of the items
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {


        var item = listEnumerator.get_current();                
        var title = item.get_displayName();
        //var id = item.get_id();
           document.getElementById('labelHTML').innerHTML += title.toString() + "<br />"; 

    }
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}</script>​
```

Comment: Can you share your current code? It is always easier to build on an foundation :)

Comment: sure Robert, I have added my code..

Comment: Great, I formatted it for you

Comment: oh..thank you Robert. I could do it ..:( sorry..!  thanks once again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
document.getElementById('labelHTML').innerHTML += "<a href='" + list.get_defaultDisplayFormUrl() + "?ID="+ item.get_id() + "' > " + title.toString() + "</a><br />"; 

//get_defaultDisplayFormUrl() - returns the relative url
```

if you need complete url, please prefix the web url.